# How can I efficiently extract an element from C#'s SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#

What is standard C# practice to get a Value associated with a key from C#'s SortedDictionary with complexity O(lgn) instead of O(2lgn)? I'm asking this because it seems that every time that you want to extract a value you need to first call ContainsKey to check if the key is there and that adds another lgn to the overall complexity. In C++ I can call .find() and check the pointer it returns against .end() and dereference that pointer if it's not equal to .end(). In Java all the keys stored are references, so the get() method returns a null if the key was not found, which is also O(lgn). So. in C#, can I do anything other that using nullable types for values to get than O(lgn) complexity? Thanks.

Comment: aren't dictionaries based off of a hash set so the O(1)

Comment: @johnny5 A dictionary/table/lookup is a concept; there are many possible ways to implement one, including a hash based structure, a tree based structure, etc.  `SortedDictionary` is implemented as a tree based structure, so lookups are O(log(n))

Comment: @johnny5 Not `SortedDictionary`. It is implemented using a red-black tree if I remember correctly.

Comment: okay cool, how does trygetvalue change the O single pass won't you get way more overhead if you fail?

Comment: @johnny5 It doesn't change the big O complexity; it does mean that you compute the hash code, and compare the item(s) for equality once, instead of twice.  So it's about twice as fast, which is the exact same asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @Servy doesn't change the theoretical big O complexity but sure changes the practical one

Comment: Oh it just computes the hashcode and doesnt throw it returns the default for that type.  I thought it was just wrapping things in a try that makes way more sense now thanks @Servy

Comment: @paulpaul1076 If you aren't interested in the asymptotic complexity then don't use big O.  And no, it's not changing the theoretical vs practical big O.  The big O is unambiguously equal in both cases, in theory and in practice.  If you want to distinguish between the costs of different algorithms at a finer grain then you need to use a different system than big O.

Comment: @Servy and what system is that?

Comment: There are lots of other systems for measuring the complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: @Servy maybe, regardless of that, I know that O(lgn) = O(2lgn), I simply worded this in a way that is easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is standard C# practice to get a Value associated with a key from C#'s SortedDictionary with complexity O(lgn) instead of O(2lgn)?

`O(log(n))` is equal to `O(2 * log(n))`, so doing two passes *is* O(log(n)).

That said, you can use `TryGetValue` to get a value *if one exists* using a single pass.

Comment: It returns a default element, if your values are ValueTypes you have no way to know if you got a default value or an associated value, if that associated value is equal to default(T).

Comment: @paulpaul1076 The return value of `TryGetValue` is a boolean indicating whether or not the value was found, so yes, you *can* distinguish between the value not being there and the value being the default value.

Answer (score 1):

To do a single lookup you can use `TryGetValue`.

```
object value;
if(dic.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{

}
```